# Prevent click if its child element in Google chart table

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have a table created using Google visualization which looks like this:

[image: sample visualization]

I have added the jQuery tooltip for the question mark

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).tooltip();
});
```

My problem is that when I click the column header it sorts the page (which I want), and even if I click on the question mark, it sorts the page (which I don't want) and at the same time, upon `mouseleave`, the tooltip doesn't close—it's just stuck on the page.

How do I get about this?

Comment: Stop the event propagation on clicking on question mark.

Comment: Yup I tried that, but doesnt work

Comment: @codermonkey Can you provide code?

Comment: my html looks like this. http://jsfiddle.net/munkeycoder/93DnY/

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#QestionMark" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  // Do something
 });
```